# How to solve equation of motion for Orbit in Einsteinian Mechanics?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, computational-physics, software

Hi i am trying to solve the following equation using runge-kutta method but it doesn't seem to work. $$\frac{dr}{d\phi}=\sqrt{\frac{2Er^4}{l^2} + \frac{2GM}{l^2} -r^2 + 2GMr}.$$  I have written a python script to solve this using runge-kutta method. My question is : is there any other way to solve this equation? Also will this have an analytical solution. I want $r$ in terms of $\phi$.

PS:
$E,M,l,G$ are constants.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/615906/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Yup i have deleted that question.

Comment: If that square root ever goes negative (at or near the turning points) the process will blow up.

Comment: @m4r35n357 Yes this is what keeps happening. I have obtained value of energy for which that hardly happens for $\phi=0 \,to\,2\pi$ but that only works for one energy and a specific initial value of $r$. Isn't there any other method to solve this?

Comment: Do you know any Hamiltonian mechanics?  That equation can be _seen as_ v = sqrt(U(r)).  If you square both sides you get "H" = v^2 - U(r) = 0.  That equation can be solved without blowing up using Hamilton's equations.  I have put the H in quotes because I am not a rigorous mathematician ;)

Comment: @m4r35n357 Yes i know hamiltonian mechanics and the hamilton's equations. Can you write/explain through an answer how would i solve this using Hamilton's equation. Thanks

Comment: Kinetic term: dT/d_rdot = 2v, Potential term: dU/dr = (differentiate U wrt r, you can do this bit!), then you have two ODEs, dU/dt = dT/d_rdot = 2v, and dT/dt = - dU/dr = - whatever you calculated.  Solve these equations using RK4 or symplectic Euler method or whatever.  Does that help?

Comment: At the end of the day, if calculations are what matters to you, isn't it better to keep the original dependence of $r = r(\tau), \, \phi = \phi(\tau), \, t = t(\tau)$ on proper time $\tau$ and simply go with a simple implementation like this one: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34304/solving-coupled-differential-equations-in-python-2nd-order/34950#34950 or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783738/couple-differential-equations-using-python/60861441#60861441

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably with the turning points $dr/d\phi = 0$ (also notice that you have to switch the sign of the right hand side after passing through it!), since if you overshoot them even by a little, you will get an imaginary value for the derivative. A solution for this problem is one of the following:

1. To work with a second-order equation for $d^2r/d\phi^2 = f(r,E,l,dr/d\phi)$, where all square-root expressions are replaced by $dr/d\phi$.
2. To choose a parametrization $r(\xi) = (r_1 + r_2) + (r_1-r_2)\sin \xi$, where $r_1,r_2$ are the roots of the equation $dr/d\phi = 0$. You should then be able to re-express the equation as $d \xi/d\phi = g(\xi,E,l)$ without the turning-point singularities.
3. Work with the implicit equation
   $$\int_{r_0}^{r} \frac{dr'}{\pm\sqrt{2Er'^2/l^2 + ...}} = \phi-\phi_0$$
   You can integrate the left-hand side by any method for definite integrals, and then you can get the series of values $r,\phi$ along the trajectory (but remember, you have to switch the sign/reflect the direction of integration once encountering the turning point).
4. You could just use your original algorithm and put checks on whether you get an imaginary value for $dr/d\phi$. If you do, you can roll back a step (which you have to have saved), and either make the step smaller, or if $dr/d\phi$ is small enough, switch the sign of $dr/d\phi$ to start integrating away from the turning point (depending how you do this, this may be associated with increased numerical error).

Comment: This is what i tried: I have three equations one is for effective poetential $V_{eff}$ and second is for $\frac{dV_{eff}}{dr}=0$ and the third one is as shown above. Now i start with solving $\frac{dV_{eff}}{dr}=0$ and i get two values of radii. Then i use these two values in the last(3rd) equation . But the problem is when i solve the third equation(shown above in my post) , in the first iteration of RK4 method i get a negative value for the expression inside square root. How can i resolve this? Why is this problem occuring?